# android app working on simulator but not on phone

Tags: android, listview

i have this app that i developed and it works great on the simulator with no errors what so ever. but the moment i try to run the same on the phone for testing, the app crashes stating filenotfoundexception. it says the file /res/drawable/divider_horizontal.9.png is missing. but actually speaking, i have never referenced that file through my code. 
i believe its a system/os file that is unavailable. i have a custom list view, i guess its the divider there...
could somebody please suggest what is wrong here. i believe this is a similar issue discussed here..but i am unable to make any sense out of it

http://code.google.com/p/transdroid/issues/detail?id=14

the listview.xml layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="left|center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:paddingBottom="5px"
    android:paddingTop="5px" android:paddingLeft="5px" >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/linkImage" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/firstLineView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" android:textColor="#FFFF00" android:text="first line title"></TextView>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/secondLineView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="second line title" android:layout_marginLeft="10px" android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#0099CC"></TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

the main xml file that calls the listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="40px">
            <Button android:id="@+id/todayButton" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="Today"
                android:textSize="12sp" android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/tomorrowButton" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="Tomorrow"
                android:textSize="12sp" android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button android:id="@+id/WeekButton" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="Future"
                android:textSize="12sp" android:layout_weight="1" />


        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/listLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
            <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="No Results" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

and the code for the same is

```
 private class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        private String eventTitleArray[];


private String eventDateArray[];
    private String eventImageLinkArray[];


    public EfficientAdapter(Context context,String[] eventTitleArray,String[] eventDateArray, String[] eventImageLinkArray){
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        this.eventDateArray=eventDateArray;
        this.eventTitleArray=eventTitleArray;
        this.eventImageLinkArray =eventImageLinkArray;

    }
    public int getCount(){
        //return XmlParser.todayEvents.size()-1;
        return this.eventDateArray.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position){
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview,null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.firstLine = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstLineView);
        holder.secondLine = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondLineView);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linkImage);
        //holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.star);
        holder.firstLine.setFocusable(false);
        holder.secondLine.setFocusable(false);
        holder.imageView.setFocusable(false);
        //holder.checkbox.setFocusable(false);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Log.i(tag, "Creating the list");
    holder.firstLine.setText(this.eventTitleArray[position]);
    holder.secondLine.setText(this.eventDateArray[position]);

    Bitmap bitmap;
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL("http://edu/images/heinz7.jpg").getContent());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("assets/heinz7.jpg");//decodeFile(getResources().getAssets().open("icon.png"));
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        try{
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(this.eventImageLinkArray[position]).getContent());}
        catch(Exception e){
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL("http://eventur.sis.pitt.edu/images/heinz7.jpg").getContent());
        }

        int width = 0;
        int height =0;
        int newWidth = 50;
        int newHeight = 40;

        try{
            width = bitmap.getWidth();
            height = bitmap.getHeight();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            width = 50;
            height = 40;
        }
        float scaleWidth = ((float)newWidth)/width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float)newHeight)/height;
        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        mat.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        try{
            Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0,0,width,height,mat,true);
            BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(newBitmap);
            holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);
            holder.imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    return convertView;
}
class ViewHolder{
    TextView firstLine;
    TextView secondLine;
    ImageView imageView;
    //CheckBox checkbox;

}
```

The stack trace

```
12-12 22:55:25.022: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:512)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:562)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:617)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at com.eventur.MainActivity$EfficientAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:566)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1274)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1661)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:610)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:673)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1519)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1113)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6156)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6156)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6156)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6156)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6156)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6156)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6156)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:950)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1529)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3977)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:128)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:499)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     ... 42 more
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/divider_horizontal_dark.9.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f020001
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1643)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:548)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:138)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     ... 46 more
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable/divider_horizontal_dark.9.png
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:417)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1636)
12-12 22:55:25.212: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11069):     ... 48 more
```

Comment: Are you seriously downloading bitmap images in a listview's getView() method? That's surely not correct. Even if it was in an asynctask, that's still not usually the best idea.

Comment: What UI theme are you using (Android standard, HTC's sense… custom?) and which phone are you testing this on? Perhaps that resource does not exist under the current UI theme.

Comment: What android version are you using in the emulator and on the phone? What do you have your sdk settings set at?

Comment: @Falmarri... well I just did that ...would you please let me know if you have any better ideas for that. i could perhaps change the code
@Juli Gorge... UI theme...i am using the standard theme.. and i tried testing this on MotoBlur.. probably you are right
@Mayra... I am using the same OS version 1.6.. sdk settings, i kinda dint understand that part..could you please elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[android app working on simulator but not on phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505009/android-app-working-on-simulator-but-not-on-phone)

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem occurring during inflation. Inflating doesn't have the best error reporting/recovery, so it throws weird cryptic messages like this up when it runs into problems. I'm confident the issue lies in listview.xml, and the problem is more than likely one of the xml attributes you've added to one of the elements. Line #6 is I think referring to either the first or second Button element. When it goes to compile, it seems to give each element just one line each. I would start by taking out all tags that aren't immediately necessary for the program to run, like gravity and layout_weight.

Sorry I can't provide a more specific answer; when you run into inflation errors like this, it's a matter of probing in the dark until you find what's wrong.

As to why this is happening on the phone and not the emulator, more than likely there's simply an operating system difference between the two (OS version, UI being used, other changes the manufacturer has made, etc). Testing on the emulator will give you a good idea of how the program is going to look and run on the phone, but offers no guarantee.

Kudos on providing so much information, it makes troubleshooting a lot easier ;-) Let me know if my advice works, or if you need more information.

Comment: @atraudes..thank you for such a detailed reply. i will surely test this by removing the less important tags..hope it does the job..

Comment: @astraudes..I tried removing the less important tags, the app still does not load in the phone..and in the emulator it loses the design it should actually have... do you think, deploying this app in any other android based phone would work?

Comment: Wait...what's that > doing on the 4th line right after the FrameLayout? Is that a typo in your post or is that in the xml too?

Comment: @astraudes... it was there in the xml (i dont know how come) ..thanks for pointing that too..i removed it and ran the program again...but it failed giving the same reason...could you please help

Comment: I signed the apk and installed the same on the phone (different phone), it worked fine. the previous phone where i was trying to install it was MotoBlur and now I installed it on Moto Droid

Comment: What happens when you try to install the unsigned package on the other phone? Same problem? MotoBlur's been known to interfere with layouts

Answer (score 0):

I tried using my own resource files with a similar extension "/res/drawable/divider_horizontal.9.png" E.G. ".9.png"  It is explained that this type of file is used for Android to know that the image has special boundaries that can adjust.  I tried creating my own buttons using this type of file extension and I was also getting errors.  I replaced my files without the ".9" extension and I no longer had any issues.  When you reference the file you should never have the extension.